# Having trouble with compiling JAVA program (in package) from command line

Tags: java, command-line, compilation

I'm not sure how to compile my JAVA program from terminal.

The "main" function is in the source file called

> "TPSP.java"

and the package is called

> "TPSP16S2"

Here is the directory:

`/Users/Scott/Desktop/COMP9103/Eclipse-code/TPSP16S2/src/TPSP16S2/TPSP.java`

What command should I use to compile it, and execute it then?

Comment: Are the classes public and from which folder are you compiling? You can change directory to `src` and use `javac TPSP16S2/TPSP.java` then `java TPSP16S2.TPSP`.

Comment: Yes they are **public**, I'll have a go with your suggestion.

Comment: @AndrewLi, it works well, thank you!

Comment: No problem, cheers